# Flextable format column to scientific notation

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for converting a column of a flextable object to scientific notation. Is this possible with the flextable package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `set_formatter()` where you can define any formatter you want.

```r
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

numbers <- c(500, 1.4, 1999999, 0.3333, 0.00001)
dataset <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:5),
  numbers = numbers)

flextable(dataset) %>% 
  set_formatter(numbers = function(x) {
    formatC(x, format = "e", digits = 3)
  })
```

[image]

Comment: This works, except for grouped data, it adds a "NA" to the empty rows between groups.

Comment: well, adapt your formatter so that it handle NA. I provided you an example based on no reprex...

Answer (score 3):

Our numbers before formatting

```
numbers = c(500, 1.4, 1999999, 0.3333, 0.00001)
```

After:

```
new_numbers <- formatC(numbers, format = "e", digits = 3)
```

Making a data.frame

```
data_flex <- data.frame(
     id = c(1:5),
     new_numbers
 )
```

Making a table

```
new_table <- flextable(data_flex)
```

[image]