# flextable: scientific formats for a table that has both very large and very small numbers

Tags: r, format, numeric, flextable

I want to display the **large numbers in scientific format** and **keep the regular format for the small numbers** to reduce column width. The real data have more columns than what is shown here.

```
dput(A)
structure(list(st2_1 = c(1437.21, 1019.03, 1199.3, 850.35, 67.32, 
586.62), st1_2 = c(0.12, 0.08, 855.64, 606.68, 687.06, 5987.41
), st2_2 = c(0.11, 0.08, 837.72, 593.98, 3659.78, 31893.5), `1-sum(e)` = c(1522.79, 
1075.11, 2092.52, 1513.48, 1052.3, 9066.99), sss_1 = c(0.05, 
0.03, 0.99, 0.7, 0.03, 0.29), sss_2 = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.43, 0.3, 
0.02, 0.19), f_1 = c(4099185668.8, 2766736655.89, 2093885714.17, 
1228712929.01, 5592860407.22, 560845021.29), f_2 = c(990125323.33, 
668282982.85, 14238156533.71, 8355091636.51, 10241029160.69, 
1026957549.35), f_3 = c(237420871.69, 160246712.8, 711346410.36, 
417425137.15, 6553794288.93, 657206264.75)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code below, provided at [Flextable format column to scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905025/flextable-format-column-to-scientific-notation), doesn't work for me.

```
A %>%
flextable::flextable() %>%
     set_formatter(numbers = function(x) {
         formatC(x, format = "e", digits = 2)
     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option: Using `format()` function with `scientific` and `digits` argument:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

A %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~
                  case_when(. < 10000 ~ format(., scientific = FALSE),
                            . >= 10000 ~ format(., scientific = TRUE, digits = 2)))) %>% 
  flextable()
```

[image]

Comment: If casting all data to string, you can not do any more conditional formatting

Comment: We could do it at the end for final output ?!

Comment: sorry for the delay. yes, by calling set_formatter, it accepts also a list of formatters (named with the colkey names), see argument `values`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that there is no column called `numbers` in your data. According to the docs (`?set_formatter`) you could pass

> Name-value pairs of functions, names should be existing col_key values

to specify the format for columns by name. Hence, to format your large numbers you could do:

```
library(flextable)

format_scientific <- function(x) {
  formatC(x, format = "e", digits = 2)
}

A |> 
  flextable() |> 
  set_formatter(
    f_1 = format_scientific,
    f_2 = format_scientific,
    f_3 = format_scientific
  )
```

[image]